# Refrence for order topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, order-topology

Can anyone give reference for order topology which covers order topology in detail with many examples other than Munkres?

Comment: There are not that many examples really.  You have subsets of the real line and ordinals. Then you can combine linearly ordered spaces using the lexicographic order https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order.

Comment: There is much in General Topology by Engelking, but much of it is  in the problems and exercises in different chapters., The book has a good index,though.

Answer (score 2):

Two references I can think of off-hand are:

[**An Introduction to Point Set Topology via Linearly Ordered Spaces**](http://www.jiblm.org/downloads/dlitem.php?id=34&category=guilfordjournal) by James Robert Boyd and George Rudolph Gordh

[**Topology and Order**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0442059116) by Leopoldo Nachbin

I haven't looked at Nachbin's book in quite a while (20+ years?), so I don't recall how advanced it is, but I do know the Boyd/Gordh book is definitely within the scope of a first course in topology.